# Cannot Remote-SSH to windows host on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I am attempting to connect to my local windows machine via ssh on VSCode.

It connects instantly from the CLI directly:

```
➜  ~ ssh windows
johnpc@DESKTOP-U5QAQJ4 MINGW64 ~
$ ls
# my windows files appear
```

The windows host is configured in my ssh config as follows:

```
Host windows
    HostName 192.168.7.208
    User johnpc
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

However, when I attempt to connect to this host using the Remote-SSH VSCode extension, I get the following output, followed by a "connection timed out" error.

```
[12:14:05.084] Log Level: 2
[12:14:05.086] remote-ssh@0.65.8
[12:14:05.086] darwin x64
[12:14:05.087] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+windows", attempt 1
[12:14:05.088] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[12:14:05.088] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[12:14:05.088] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[12:14:05.089] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[12:14:05.089] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[12:14:05.089] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[12:14:05.089] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[12:14:05.089] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[12:14:05.090] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[12:14:05.090] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[12:14:05.090] SSH Resolver called for host: windows
[12:14:05.090] Setting up SSH remote "windows"
[12:14:05.094] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/33/_y9rjvqs5qb_9kqnjkdsqmn00000gr/T/vscode-remote-ssh-d59726ea-install.lock
[12:14:05.097] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/xss/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-d59726ea-7f6ab5485bbc008386c4386d08766667e155244e-0.65.8/data.json
[12:14:05.099] Using commit id "7f6ab5485bbc008386c4386d08766667e155244e" and quality "stable" for server
[12:14:05.103] Install and start server if needed
[12:14:05.112] PATH: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
[12:14:05.113] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[12:14:05.122] > OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

[12:14:05.135] askpass server listening on /var/folders/33/_y9rjvqs5qb_9kqnjkdsqmn00000gr/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-7c5258e395d834dd29687f462a9d8b0f6991a74c.sock
[12:14:05.152] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/33/_y9rjvqs5qb_9kqnjkdsqmn00000gr/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-0574ebf0bc7748cd079f9c7446cf741428682ad7.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","49840","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","windows"],"dataFilePath":"/Users/xss/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-d59726ea-7f6ab5485bbc008386c4386d08766667e155244e-0.65.8/data.json"}
[12:14:05.152] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":"1","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/xss/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Renderer)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/xss/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.8/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/33/_y9rjvqs5qb_9kqnjkdsqmn00000gr/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-7c5258e395d834dd29687f462a9d8b0f6991a74c.sock"}
[12:14:05.155] Spawned 50798
[12:14:05.280] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=50799
[12:14:05.298] stderr> OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
[12:14:05.696] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:de8MMkFj9OesKnoJGzuHZlBRw9BfkLCD2Rvpn2jtY6g
[12:14:06.104] stderr> Authenticated to 192.168.7.208 ([192.168.7.208]:22).
[12:14:06.490] > ready: f87615babce1
[12:14:06.591] > MINGW64_NT-10.0-19042 3.1.7-340.x86_64 2021-03-26 22:17 UTC
```

[image: screenshot of connection timeout]

Any ideas what might be going on? Feels especially weird because the messages look like everything is succeeded, but still emit as stderr? `stderr> Authenticated`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out (kind of). Remote-SSH only seems to work if Powershell is configured as the default ssh shell in windows.

On the windows machine, I had to run:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

Previously, I had been using git-bash as the default terminal (which is what I'd prefer):

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Prog
ram Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

Now every time I log in I have to run `& 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe'` to reach the git-bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Firewall/Antivirus?

A Timeout would appear if there is no answer, even if local.
(Please be carefull if you want to disable your Firewall complete for testing.)